# My code should keep asking for the correct "password" until it is given correctly, is it correct?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

```
while (true) {

            String password = "carrot";

            String inputtedPassword = reader.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Type the password:");

            if (password.equals(inputtedPassword)) {
                System.out.println("Right!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong!");
            }
            if (password.equals(inputtedPassword)) {
                break;
            }


        }
```

I'm doing an excercise that asks for a code that keeps asking for the correct "password" until it is given correctly, then it can stop asking. This is the code that I wrote and when I execute it it does what it should, but when I submit it I get an error message that says "Program should keep asking the password until it is given correctly". I am confused.

Comment: why two  `if (password.equals(inputtedPassword))` ?

Comment: That condition with the break at the end might be causing confusion. Why don't you just put the break after you print "Right"?

Comment: You could just run your code and watch what it does...

Comment: Also, most people would appreciate if you first ask them for input, then try to read it. Makes it easier to know what you're supposed to enter.

Answer (score 0):

You should just run your code and see whether the result is expected!

If you did, you will see that it prints "Type the password:" *after* you enter the password. This is caused by calling `nextLine` before you print.

You should reorder the two lines like this:

```
System.out.println("Type the password:");
String inputtedPassword = reader.nextLine();
```

Other than that, your code appears to work perfectly.

However, there are some lines that are redundant.

This:

```
if (password.equals(inputtedPassword)) {
    System.out.println("Right!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Wrong!");
}
if (password.equals(inputtedPassword)) {
    break;
}
```

can be shortened to:

```
if (password.equals(inputtedPassword)) {
    System.out.println("Right!");
    break;
} else {
    System.out.println("Wrong!");
}
```

Also, I suggest you to change `password` to a constant if it is never changed:

```
final String PASSWORD = "carrot";
```

Comment: If you start to "shorten" OPs code, then also remove the redundant `else` branch. There is no need to it, when the `if` branch breaks the loop. Just print `"Wrong!"` right after the `if`. And constants are `static` and `final`, not just `final`.

Comment: @Tom IMO, with an `else` branch, the code is clearer and easier to read. That's just my style I guess. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Yeah ok, some need a sign to explain the obivous stuff, I guess :P.